# I2C interface IOH,IIL,IIH,IOL values

Tags: i2c

When 2 digital devices are interfaced VOH,VIL,VIH,VOL,IIH,IOL,IOH,IIH will be compared for 2 devices as an logic compatibility check. I have do the same check for I2C interface. Slave device datasheet(EEPROM IC:M24M01) do not provide values for IIH,IOL,IOH,IIH. I have went through the datasheet of 2 other ICs, their datasheets also do not provide the values. In that scenario how the current through the SCL and SDA lines can be calculated.

Comment: [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group0/cb/91/ba/7d/0b/c1/4d/f6/CD00147128/files/CD00147128.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00147128.pdf) page 26 table 12, page 27 table 13.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your question is. So the answer is a bit generic. 
The voltage levels on SDA and SCL lines are set by the pull up resistors when they are not pulled down by any of the devices on the bus. This sets the high level voltage. Each devices ability to pull down sets the low level.

I think you are trying to enforce a design regime suitable for logic circuits (TTL, CMOS, etc.) onto a bus (I2C) that does not fit. I don't think you need to find these currents. You should follow the design recommendations for the I2C bus.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? Of course the i2c port of a device has bias currents, a VIH, a VIL and a VOL. The only missing parameter is VOH, which is about the only right thing you state.